# Javascript ID Number not working after 2 digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom, jquery-events

I have this issue in dealing with ID number. I tried to delete some of the added rows when it reached above 10, it does not delete the correct row. Like if I will the row 11. It will delete the row 1 instead of 11, it can only find the #field1 not the #field11. can any body help me to solve this issue?

```
$('.remove-me').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1);
        var fieldID = "#field" + fieldNum;
        $(this).remove();
        $(fieldID).remove();

    });
```

Comment: This line makes no sense to me at all: `var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1);`, unless you can show us your DOM and the IDs you are working with.

Comment: Looks like you're assuming the last character of the id is the number you need. Which is obviously always just one character (last character of "field11" is "1").

Comment: `var fieldNum = /\d+/.exec(this.id)[0];` will return the first set of digits found in `this.id` (given that it does contain some)

Comment: The cleanest way would be to save the number as data instead of scraping it from the id.

Comment: It is just poor form to either assume the number of digits at the end of the string or use a Regex. Save the id as an integer.

Answer (score 2):

try regex if your ids always like `field..`

```js
$('.remove-me').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var numberPattern = /\d+/g;
        var fieldNum = this.id.match( numberPattern ).join('');
        var fieldID = "#field" + fieldNum;
        console.log(fieldNum)
        $(this).remove();
        $(fieldID).remove();

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn remove-me"id="field10">10</a>
<a class="btn remove-me"id="field1">1</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are cutting of only the last character of the `id` as evident by the `this.id.length - 1`. Can you try something like this:

```
$('.remove-me').click(function(e) {
    if (this.id.match(/[0-9]+$/)) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var fieldNum = this.id.match(/[0-9]+$/)[0];
        var fieldId = '#field' + fieldNum;

        $(this).remove();
        $(fieldId).remove();
    }
});
```

By matching against `/[0-9]+$/` you can cut of any string of digits at the end of your `id`.

Answer (score -1):

I will guess you actually mean this

```js
$('.remove-me').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest("li").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>0 <button type="button" class="remove-me">Remove</button></li>
  <li>1 <button type="button" class="remove-me">Remove</button></li>
  <li>2 <button type="button" class="remove-me">Remove</button></li>
  <li>3 <button type="button" class="remove-me">Remove</button></li>
  <li>4 <button type="button" class="remove-me">Remove</button></li>
</ul>
```

and not this

```js
$('.remove-me').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const $first10 = $(this).next().find("li").slice(0,10);
  $("ul").html($first10)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="remove-me">Remove from 10</button>
<ul>
  <li>0 </li>
  <li>1 </li>
  <li>2 </li>
  <li>3 </li>
  <li>4 </li>
  <li>5 </li>
  <li>6 </li>
  <li>7 </li>
  <li>8 </li>
  <li>9 </li>
  <li>10 </li>
  <li>11 </li>
  <li>12 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're only getting the last digit of the id, so it won't work for double digits. If you like ugly solutions, and some coders are into that kind of thing, then use regular expressions. But if you prefer a bit of elegance in your life, use base 36 (0-9A-Z) so that you have way more single digit numbers before you run out.